# Integrating Google Plus in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

I'm trying to integrate Google Plus authentication, and have followed a tutorial in [this link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in).

When I add `#import "GPPSignIn.h"` I get the error :

> `GPPSignIn.h not found`.

However, when I use `#import "/Users/MH/Documents/TestGooglePlus/GooglePlus.framework/Headers/GPPSignIn.h"` it works.

After compilation my application crash and I have this message:

> `-[__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc71b568010`

Comment: any answer or suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two problems.

First, the header.

See: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in#enable_sign_in

```
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h>
```

Second, you're missing an important linker flag.

See: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started#step_2_initialize_the_google_client

Step 6.2:

> Add the ObjC linker flag to the app target's build settings:
>
> Other Linker Flags: -ObjC

Comment: thanks Steve, i have added -ObjC now i have another error : ld: 27 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: If my post answered the question you originally asked, would you mind marking it as accepted for the next person who searches for your question? In regards to your second question, it sounds like you've linked some class into your app twice. I'd need to see what the symbol was (which the build logs will tell you.) Please post a new question.